# Handling many-to-many relationship in a sql query

Tags: sql, database-design, many-to-many

So as you know in data modeling, the many-to-many relationships are handled by creating a bridge table. This will enable us to have foreign key constraints.

My question relating to query data from tables that have many-to-many relationships.

I will give an example. Let's say we have the following tables

Table 1

```
Column 1
Column 2
Column 3
```

Table 2

```
Column 1
Column 4
Column 5
```

Table 3 (bridge table)

```
Column 1
```

Ok, so when I tried to query data from table 1 and left joining with table 2 I got the same results as query data from table left joining with table 3 and left joining with table 2. And that makes me wonder if the bridge table is a necessary step to include in a SQL query!

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Your bridge table has just one column, which suggests that you are confusing one-to-many relationships (or many one-to-one), and many-to-many relationships.

In a one-to-many relationship, the child table refers directly to the parent table, and there is no need for a bridge table:

```
create table orders (
    order_id int primary key,
    order_date date,
    ...
);

create table order_items (
    order_item_id int primary key,
    order_id int references orders(order_id),
    ...
)
```

In a many-to-many relationship, the bridge table has (at least) *two columns*, one for each of the referential table that come into play in the relation:

```
create table authors (
    author_id int primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    ...
);

create table books (
    book_id int primary key,
    title varchar(50),
    ...
);

create table book_authors (
    author_id int references authors(author_id),
    book_id int references books(book_id),
    primary key (author_id, book_id)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Maybe I didn't make my example clear.

Table 2 and Table 3 have descriptive information for Column 1, and each table has repeated descriptive rows for Column1. There are no facts or dimensions here. Why tables 2 and 3 aren't flattened in one table, because I have my reasons. 

By explaining this to you, I actually answered my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's make your example less abstract. There are posts with dislikes and likes. Table 1 = likes, Table 2 = dislikes.

- Table likes (post_id, who, why)
- Table dislikes (post_id, who, why)

The bridge table is then

- Table posts (post_id, content)

This is an example where two child tables are related by a parent table. You don't create the bridge table in order to get an m:n relation between the two child tables, but because the child tables make no sense without their parent table. The child tables are m:n related, but we don't usually call this an m:n relation, because the tables are only losely related (a like belongs to a post and a dislike belongs to a post, but the like doesn't really belong to the dislike).

When talking about m:n relations, we are usally not talking about parent/child relationship.

An example: An order can contain many products and a product can be in many orders.

- Table orders (order_id, date)
- Table products (product_id, name, price)

The bridge table is the position in the order:

- Table order_detail (order_id, product_id, amount)

There is no parent/child relation between orders and products, but the two are related, because products get ordered. This is what we typically call an m:n relation. The bridge table establishes the relation between order and product.